# Flask-SQLAlchemy updating whole object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I was wondering if there was a shorter way to update an entire object,
let's say I have an object "Package" declared like this :

```
class Package(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['name','version','maintainer','uploaders']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    version = db.Column(db.String(15))
    architecture = db.Column(db.String(255))
    maintainer = db.Column(db.String(255))
    sha256 = db.Column(db.String(200))
    sha1 = db.Column(db.String(50))
    md5sum = db.Column(db.String(50))
    depends = relationship('Package',
                           secondary=package_to_package,
                           primaryjoin=id==package_to_package.c.left_package_id,
                           secondaryjoin=id==package_to_package.c.right_package_id,
                           backref='neededBy')
    recommends = relationship('Package',
                           secondary=package_recommended,
                           primaryjoin=id==package_recommended.c.left_package_id,
                           secondaryjoin=id==package_recommended.c.right_package_id,
                           backref='recommendedBy')
    lastUpdate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    distributionId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('distribution.id'))
    componentId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('component.id'))
    status = db.Column(db.String(50))
    format = db.Column(db.String(25))
    uploaders = db.Column(db.String(255))
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.lastUpdate = datetime.utcnow()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Package : %r Version : %r Maintainer : %r componentId : %d >' % (
            self.name,
            self.version,
            self.maintainer,
            self.componentId)
```

I've got a celery task that update those objects, 
my first approach to update this object was :

```
 if isinstance(package, Package):
                # Check if Distribution already Exists
                recordedPackage = Package.query.filter_by(name=package.name,
                                                            distributionId=package.distributionId,
                                                            componentId=package.componentId).first()
                app.logger.debug("Does it already Exists ?")
                if recordedPackage is None:
                    package.depends = packagesNeeded
                    db.session.add(package)
                elif isinstance(recordedPackage,Package) :
                    app.logger.info("updating %r"%(recordedPackage))
                    recordedPackage = package
                    db.session.commit()
```

this approach doesn't update anything, so I had to do this :

```
elif isinstance(recordedPackage,Package) :
                    app.logger.info("updating %r"%(recordedPackage))
                    recordedPackage.version = package.version
                    recordedPackage.depends = packagesNeeded
                    recordedPackage.maintainer = package.maintainer
                    recordedPackage.md5sum = package.md5sum
                    recordedPackage.sha1 = package.sha1
                    recordedPackage.sha256 = package.sha256
                    recordedPackage.lastUpdate = datetime.utcnow()
                    [...]
                    db.session.commit()
```

it's really dynamic or clean to do so.
Is there a way to update an entire object (without it's id of course) ?
Thank you for your awnsers

Comment: What do you mean by " update an entire object (without it's id of course) " ?

Comment: The package object is retrieved from outside the app, I'll need to update every property of the object and update it in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've used the dir method with the getattr/setattr
to implement an `update` method within the class like proposed by GG_Python
which does looks like this :

```
 def update(self,newPackage):
    newPackageAttributes = [a for a in dir(newPackage) if not a.startswith('__')]
    for key in newPackageAttributes:
        try:
            if getattr(self,key) != getattr(newPackage, key) \
                    and key != 'id'\
                    and key != 'name':
                if type(getattr(newPackage, key)) == str:
                    setattr(self,key,getattr(newPackage, key))
        except AttributeError:
            app.logger.debug("attribute not found, no pb")
    self.lastUpdate = datetime.utcnow()
```

this way I don't update InstanceState and so on,
I could add later some check ( like the name should be the same etc...)
which give me something like this on the method that parses the packages :

```
recordedPackage = Package.query.filter_by(name=package.name,
                                        distributionId=package.distributionId,
                                        componentId=package.componentId).first()
app.logger.debug("Does it already Exists ?")
if recordedPackage is None:
    package.depends = packagesNeeded
    db.session.add(package)
elif isinstance(recordedPackage,Package) :
    app.logger.info("updating %r"%(recordedPackage))
    recordedPackage.update(package)

db.session.commit()
```

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

use the `update` method; i usually create a dictionary to make things readable:

```
dct = {"version": package.version, ... , "lastUpdate":datetime.utcnow()}
recordedPackage.update(dct)
db.session.commit()
```

Note that you'll need to commit even after the `add`, so consider moving the `commit` statement outside the if/elif condition.

Comment: the `update` method doesn't exist with a flask-sqlachemy `db.Model`, I've added a `update` method within my class.

Comment: `update` exists on the table. `Package.__table__.update(...)`.